# Linux shell script - copy folder from VPS to local PC

Tags: shell, vps

I want to write a shell script (linux) who will copy a folder (located on my VPS-OVH) on my local pc.
I don't know how to do that. If someone can help me on this that would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rsync` is typically used for this. You usually don't need a script for this.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to figure out how to do it manually from your commandline. When you know how to do that, you should start looking into the scripting of it. Start with a [tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) and post code if you get stuck.